# making osx modal

Tags: objective-c, macos, scripting, applescript

I've used applescript a lot, and I love it. But for some workflows it would be really neat to be able to go into a "mode" where single keystrokes would allow me to launch scripts, choose options in dialogs, interact with apps etc. It's my impression that this is impossible with applescript alone but doable with objective-c. What are my options? What do I google to start reading up on this?

PS. If there are several options I'd prefer the ones that work best with applescript (or python).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is learning AppleScriptObjC, You write an cocoa application with AppleScript syntax. Like Apple says, with AppleScriptObjC you can write first class applications in AppleScript. If you have no experience with cocoa it can be very time consuming job to use the right objects and it's methods. So before you think, like many others, that there is a huge lack of documentation, your answers can be found in the Cocoa-Objective-C documentations and examples. A good book for people who are familiar with AppleScript already is Shane Stanley's AppleScriptObjC explored, that can be found here http://www.macosxautomation.com/applescript/apps/index.html.

Because you know python as well you could use PyObjC as well but I don't have experience with it.